# Adding a 'Load More' button below ItemsControl in windows phone 8.1 Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, itemscontrol

I am implementing a RSS reader application and i am using ItemsControl to display the news items. I tried to add a 'Load More' button below the ItemsControl like this

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>       

   <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl"  Margin="10,10,10,0" Grid.Row="0">
     <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <VirtualizingStackPanel>                       
       </VirtualizingStackPanel>
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>

    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
          <ScrollViewer>
            <ItemsPresenter />
          </ScrollViewer>
         </ControlTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.Template>
     </ItemsControl>

    <TextBlock x:Name="loadMoreTextBlock" Grid.Row="1" Text="Load more"/>
</Grid>
```

But the textblock is not displayed in the end of the scrolling and it is always visible in the root grid. I want to display the 'Load More' text only at the end of the itemscontrol as the user scrolls down to bottom.

Changing the ItemsControl.Template like this

```
  <ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
      <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
          <ItemsPresenter />
          <TextBlock x:Name="loadMoreTextBlock" Text="Load more"/> 
         </StackPanel>               
      </ScrollViewer>
     </ControlTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.Template>
```

solves the problem, but the performance of the ItemsControl is poor. Do you have any better idea or suggestions?

Thanks
Vinoth Selvaraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spent at least 2 hours figuring out why virtualization is lost in this scenario, but the only way I managed to get around this problem is by sticking to the ControlTemplate you provided first ->

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ItemsPresenter />
    </ScrollViewer>
</ControlTemplate>
```

and making sure that you put the 'Load more' item into your viewmodel's collection that you bind your ItemsSource to. In this case you might need to apply a different ItemTemplate to the last member of the list, that can be achieved via a custom DataTemplateSelector.
However, when clicking 'Load more' you would have to relocate this special list item to the end of the list again.

On the whole, I'd suggest going for the 2nd approach you proposed, i.e. place 'Load more' below the list OR maybe consider changing the whole concept and use some kind of paging mechanism, whereas you can only see the first few hundred entries in the list and pressing some buttons shows the previous / next few hundreds.